# no Transaction emails are being sent

Tags: orders, ce-1.9.0.1, transaction

im using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 and no Transaction emails are being sent at all. The customer does not get a order conformation email. The admin does not get an order email. And when you sign up you dont get a welcome email. There are no errors in the logs and my hosting company says everything is good on their end. I have also installed SMTP pro when I ran the test with in SMTP pro it did send the test email and I recivied it. But still no other emails are sent out. Can some one help me figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

You might wish to consider the "Mandrill" plugin which will take over all Magento emails, you'll then have a control panel where you can monitor emails sent and see bounce reports, deliveries and all communication from the site.  The extension is free and you have an allowance of 12,000 emails per month.  This should resolve any hosting or server issues as this will be handled by the 3rd party..